# Call an API method via React Redux on Browser close using 'beforeunload' event listener

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, addeventlistener, onbeforeunload

I have a React App and I want there to be a DELETE call to an API method when a user closes the browser. I have therefore added this into the `App.js`:

```
import myReduxAction from "./Redux/Actions/admin/superAdminActions";

  componentDidMount() {
    ...
    this.setupBeforeUnloadListener();
  }

  setupBeforeUnloadListener = () => {
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (ev) => {
          this.methodToCallBeforeUnload();
          debugger;
      });
  };

  methodToCallBeforeUnload= () => {
    myReduxAction.myActionMethodSynchronous();
  }
```

When the browser is closed, I can enter a debugger into the above code and it seems to run through fine. However, I notice that the API method is not being hit. My Action method looks something like this:

```
const myActionMethodSynchronous = () => {
    debugger;
    return function () {
            debugger;
        try {
            myApi.myAPIMethodSynchronous();
        } catch (error) {
            // Code to handle errors
        }
    };
};
```

And the actual call to the API:

```
  const myAPIMethodSynchronous= () => {
    debugger;
    return axios.delete(`/MyAPI/myapimethodname/`);
  };
```

I have added 2x`debugger;` to the Action Method. One above the `return function` and another below. The first one gets hit, however the second one (and the one inside the api call) are never hit.

Am I missing something obvious here. I also have a button that is wired up to this Action Method and that seems to work fine. I only seem to have this problem when trying to initiate it from closing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

What the browser/device do you use? onbeforeunload and onunload are not supported in all browsers. For example, this code:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    fetch('/api/some_method1', {
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    })
}
window.onunload = function () {
    fetch('/api/some_method2', {
        method:'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    })
}
```

works fully in Chrome and Opera (I got both requests), in Safari I got only onbeforeunload, and it seems that it is not working on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using Chrome on a Windows desktop. I can step into the onbeforeunload function I have created, it is when I step into Redux land that the problem seems to happen.

Comment: And what the exactly debugger was called? It seems that it is from addEventListener, because of this.methodToCallBeforeUnload(); just return the function but not calling it